# Disable hidden field validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, request

I've got an hiddenfield filled with HTML which is used for a modal pop up box at page load.
How ever, on postback the content of the hiddenfield are giving exception:

```
A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (ctl00$MainContentCP$hfContent="<div>
```

I'm aware of the method were you could disable the validation for the whole page with:

```
validateRequest="false"
```

But since this page got some textfields I want to protect from scripting attacks this might not be the right solution.

Can I somehow disable the validation ONLY for the hiddenfield?

Code causing exception:

```
  <asp:HiddenField ID="hfContent" runat="server" />

  if (!Page.IsPostBack)
  {
        Pages pages = new Pages();
        hfContent.Value = pages.getPageById(14).PageContent; //this
  }
```

Comment: Minor note: Scripting attacks are only preventable  by encoding the ***output*** not the input.  ***You should already be encoding all output.***  Then you don't need to worry abou the input, at least as far as XSS attacks go.  Validation prevents invalid data from coming in, so in addtion you should be using regular Validator controls, but IMO the validateRequest isn't absolutely necessary, and if you're encoding all output, you can safely disable it for the page.

Comment: what asp.net framework version are you using?

Comment: @DavidStratton: Allright thought it validated the output aswell. For output validation, should I use Server.HtmlEncode() or what would you suggest?

Comment: @ElYusubov: I'm using 4.0 ASP.NET

Comment: Server.HtmlEncode will do, but I prefer the Microsoft Anti-Xss library.  It uses a whitelist approach, and offers additional funcitonality like GetSafeHtmlFragemnt() that lets innocuous html tags come through un-encoded.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/aa973814.aspx

Comment: Try the HtmlEncode, if that does not work, then list your code. Most probably you are missing something.

Comment: @ElYusubov The lines causing the error is this: hfContent.Value = pages.getPageById(14).PageContent;

I've tried htmlencoding, urlencoding etc. Still get the same exception. But I think I'll just disable validationRequest and htmlencode output.

Comment: Can you list the whole code in question body? it is not clear in comments.

Answer (score 0):

If you creating a 4.0 ASP.NET application see this:
[ASP.NET Request Validation section](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like error is in a declaration. Try the following:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfContent" Value="String" runat="server" />
```

Also double check the value which is assigned to your hidden field. 
In your code, you need to **remove line** `Pages pages = new Pages();`

Comment: I'm not interested in binding the value for the hiddenfield from the aspx file. It has to happen from the codebehind since the value is collected from the database and need to be changeable.

The value I assign are the problem, since it contains several illegal characters "<& etc

Comment: Pages pages = new Pages(); your page object is empty, so pages.getPageById(14) will return null or exception

Comment: No, why should that object be empty? Pages are a class file which obviously contains the getPageById method and I know there is are page with id 14. 
If there wasn't I'm pretty sure I would get a null exception instead of this.